# MySQL SUM множество к множеству

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

=) Есть у меня четыре таблицы: **stocks, items, categories, taxonomy** Это как все поняли - склад. Нужно вывести категории с подсчетом количества позиций в каждой категории. Вот пример таблиц: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQTgED7YfXWSRti1zt2Y5i/21

Я смог только вывести категории:

```
SELECT `c`.`name`,
`i`.`count`
FROM `categories` AS `c` 

JOIN `taxonomy` AS `t` ON `c`.`id` = `t`.`term`
JOIN `stocks` AS `st` ON `st`.`id` = `t`.`object`
JOIN `items` AS `i` ON `i`.`id` = `t`.`object`

WHERE (`st`.`id` = 1);
```

Таблицы:

- **stocks** - это склады
- **Items** - Позиции на складе с текущим количеством
- **Categories** - Категории позиций на складе
- **Taxonomy** - Объединяющая таблица. По задумке она должна объединять  склад с позицией и позицию с категорией.

**Taxonomy связывает разные таблицы:**

- если `type='category'`, то это связка склада(term) с категорией(object)
- если `type='item'`, то это связка категории(term) с позицией(object)

Суть задачи такова, что нужно вывести список с категориями (что я и сделал) и вторым значением (столбцом) нужно вывести количество позиций в каждой из категорий используя значение ***count*** из таблицы **items**

Comment: Нужно - выводите, мы не против. Хотите помощи - показывайте, что ВЫ ЛИЧНО сделали для решения задачи, в чём именно столкнулись с проблемой, и какой именно.

Comment: я смог только вывести список категорий 
SELECT `c`.`name`
 FROM `categories` AS `c` 
    
    JOIN `taxonomy` AS `t` ON `c`.`id` = `t`.`term`
    JOIN `stocks` AS `st` ON `st`.`id` = `t`.`object`
    
    WHERE (`st`.`id` = 1);

Comment: Важные дополнения помещайте в текст вопроса (ссылка "править" под ним), а не в комментарии.

Comment: `Это как все поняли - склад`. Нет, не поняли. Изобразите что значат эти таблицы, какие связи подразумеваются. Почему taxonomy.object обозначает разные сущности и от чего это зависит?

Comment: В таблице taxonomy на что ссылается object, а на что term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в таблице `taxonomy` у вас ссылки на разные сущности.
Имея в виду что-то одно, нужно добавлять соответствующий фильтр по полю `type`.

В первом приближении это выглядит так:

```
SELECT st.name
  , cat.name category
  , i.name item, i.count
FROM stocks st
JOIN taxonomy t_st ON t_st.type='item' AND t_st.object=st.id
JOIN items i ON i.id = t_st.term
JOIN taxonomy t_cat ON t_cat.type='category' AND t_cat.object=i.id
JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = t_cat.term
```

К этому уже можно добавить требуемые фильтры/группировки:

```
SELECT st.name
  , cat.name category
  , GROUP_CONCAT(i.name) items
  , SUM(i.count) cnt
FROM stocks st
JOIN taxonomy t_st ON t_st.type='item' AND t_st.object=st.id
JOIN items i ON i.id = t_st.term
JOIN taxonomy t_cat ON t_cat.type='category' AND t_cat.object=i.id
JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = t_cat.term
WHERE st.id = 1
GROUP BY st.id, cat.id, st.name, cat.name
```

---

*Я бы всё-таки рекомендовал бы разделить taxonomy на несколько таблиц и добавить соответствующие ограничения внешнего ключа(foreign keys)*